# Upgrade MongoDB past 2.4.10

Tags: mongodb

It's 2018, and the current version of MongoDB for the Raspbian package manager is only version 2.4.10.  This is a problem, because this old MongoDB version is becoming so stale that it won't work with the latest drivers.  I can't connect my NoSQL browser to it anymore, and I expect my applications will stop working as well if I upgrade those drivers.

Can we get a new version of MongoDB, at least version 2.6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Unusually, the Raspbian repositories are out of sync with the official [Debian repositories](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mongodb) which host version 3.2.11 for Stretch. I checked the Raspbian repos and Raspbian Stretch only has 2.4.14 available.

There are unofficial builds for Stretch, mind you, such as one from [Andy Felong](https://andyfelong.com/2017/08/mongodb-3-0-14-for-raspbian-stretch/) which provides 3.0.14.

If you're desperate you could also try [building from source](http://koenaerts.ca/compile-and-install-mongodb-on-raspberry-pi/); commenters there suggest that version 3.2 works with Stretch.

Note that although the newer Pis may be 64-bit, that probably won't help with finding a pre-compiled package—your Pi runs the ARM architecture, whereas the pre-built packages are for `x86_64` (the architecture used in most desktop and laptop PCs). They won't be compatible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [mongoPi](https://www.mongo-pi.com/) project. I've tried it on my Pi 3 (on Razbian 9, kernel 4.9.59) but couldn't make it run. I didn't really put much effort into trying to make it run, so it might work if you tweaked it a bit, though it seems versions 3.4 and 3.5 were compiled on 64-bit OpenSUSE, so those versions might only work on 64-bit systems? They have a 32-bit 3.0 version there as well if that will be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, the Raspberry Pi 3 Model b+ will be 64 bit, so hopefully mongo 64 bit will install on the new model.  Has anybody tested this yet?  I intend to buy one as soon as they come out for sale.  https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/

**Edit**
As of 2018-09-30 Raspberian is still only x86, so even though the hardware supports x64, the OS is not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't officially support the Pi for new releases. I have compiled the community edition and have MongoDB 6.x running on a Pi with 64-bit Debian. Feel free to raise an issue on [this repo](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries) if you encounter  any issues getting these binaries to run. I also have fairly involved step-by-step instructions to cross-compile the MongoDB project yourself.